# Strange behavior when modifying logical arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an array that contains a bunch of logical values, it looks like:

`test = [1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 ...]`.

If I want to change a normal array of scalar values - lets say

`a = [1 2 3 4]`

I could do:

`a(a == 1) = 5`

and the result would be

`[5 2 3 4]`

As expected.

However if I do:

`test(test == 0) = 5`

I get back something *unexpected*:

`[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1....`

All of the 0s have been changed to 1!

I suspect this is because the array is filled with logicals, and because of typechecking MATLAB coerces any value that is not `1` or `0` to the closest logical value - but I want to confirm. This is surely strange.

Comment: Any nonzero numeric value is converted to logical 1 (true), and zeros are converted to logical 0 (false).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because your array is boolean, and `5` evaluates to `true` in boolean, which displays as `1`. In English, your code `test(test == 0) = 5` translates to "set all False values to True". The result is an all-`true` array, i.e. all ones.

Comment: Yep converting to an array of doubles fixed it up for me.